# Wordpress/PHP splashscreen

Tags: php, wordpress, splash-screen

I would like a splashscreen (php page) showing up when a user enters my site, but only once. Any easy way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Once per session/visit or once forever?

Answer (score 2):

Set a $_SESSION variable and check it if its set.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['userwashere'])){
        //show the site code
} else {
       //show the splashscreen code
       $_SESSION['userwashere'] = true;
}
```